# How to execute a statement in oracle as a different user?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have created a new user account and gave them select and update permission on a table. Now I want to test if everything is correct by running select statement on those tables as the newly created user. Is there a command that would allow to 'run as'? If not is there a command that allows one to switch the active user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [proxy user](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:21575905259251).
So, you can make your user a proxy user (`GRANT CONNECT THROUGH` your user to the user you want to check with) and then connect with that user using your own password.